# Lambda Expressions

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

A point from ISO draft n3290 section 5.1.2 paragraph, point 19:

> The closure type associated with a
>   lambda-expression has a deleted
>   (8.4.3)  default constructor and a
>   deleted copy assignment operator. It
>   has an  implicitly-declared copy
>   constructor (12.8) and may have an
>   implicitly declared move constructor
>   (12.8). [ Note: The copy/move
>   constructor is implicitly defined in
>   the same way as any other implicitly
>   declared copy/move constructor would
>   be implicitly defined. —end note ]

Can any one please ....tell some example for this point to understand?

Is there any chance/way to check the Closure object(type)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The closure type associated with a lambda-expression has a deleted (8.4.3) default constructor

```
int main() {
    auto closure = [](){};
    typedef decltype(closure) ClosureType;

    ClosureType closure2;   // <-- not allowed

    return 0;
}
```

and a deleted copy assignment operator. It has an implicitly-declared copy constructor (12.8) and may have an implicitly declared move constructor (12.8).

```
#include <utility>

int main() {
    auto closure = [](){};
    typedef decltype(closure) ClosureType;

    ClosureType closure2 = closure;   // <-- copy constructor
    ClosureType closure3 = std::move(closure);  // <-- move constructor
    closure2 = closure3;              // <-- copy assignment (not allowed)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ..Is there any way/chance of explaing ..this point ..in terms of a class Example

Comment: I believe that this is well-formed though: `auto closure = []{}; decltype(closure) c{};`. That may be changed by a defect report for C++0x rev1 though.

Answer (score 4):

```
struct LambdaExample{
  // deleted operations = not allowed
  LambdaExample() = delete;
  LambdaExample& operator=(LambdaExample const&) = delete;

  // generated by the compiler:
  LambdaExample(LambdaExample const& other);
  LambdaExample(LambdaExample&& other);

  // anything else a lambda needs
};
```

For your second question, if you mean that you can look into the implementation, then nope, not possible. It's created on-the-fly by the compiler. If you mean to get the type of the lambda, sure:

```
auto l = [](){};
typedef decltype(l) closure_type;
```

Comment: yes the closure obj type is created on-the-fly by the compiler..atleast is there any chance to check whether it exists or not

Comment: @user: What do you mean with "exists"?